# How Manipulating a matrix and a graphic in only one Manipulate?

Tags: matrix, manipulate, graphics3d

I have to manipulate a matrix and graphics in one big Manipulate-Block.

This way:

```
Manipulate[Matrixform[mat],Graphics3D[]]
```

How can I achieve that?

Ok, here my Code:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[
  {
   Switch[x, 
    "Streckung", {GraphicsComplex[streckung[a, b, c], Polygon[i]]}, 
    "Verschiebung", {GraphicsComplex[
      wuerfel[a, b, c, verschiebung, k], Polygon[i]]}, 
    "Parallelprojektion", {GraphicsComplex[
      wuerfel[a, b, c, verschiebung, k], Polygon[i]], Green, Polygon[
      Transpose [
        ReplacePart[
         Transpose[
          wuerfel[a, b, c, verschiebung, 
            k].{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}], {{_, 2}, {_, 
            4}, {_, 6}, {_, 8}} :> Sequence[]]][[{1, 2, 4, 3}, All]]],
      Blue, Polygon[
      Transpose [
        ReplacePart[
         Transpose[
          wuerfel[a, b, c, verschiebung, 
            k].{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}], {{_, 3}, {_, 
            4}, {_, 7}, {_, 8}} :> Sequence[]]][[{1, 2, 4, 3}, 
        All]]], Red, Polygon[
      Transpose [
        ReplacePart[
         Transpose[
          wuerfel[a, b, c, verschiebung, 
            k].{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}], {{_, 5}, {_, 
            6}, {_, 7}, {_, 8}} :> Sequence[]]][[{1, 2, 4, 3}, 
        All]]]}, 
    "x-Drehung", {GraphicsComplex[wdrehungx[w], Polygon[i]]},
    "y-Drehung", {GraphicsComplex[wdrehungy[w], Polygon[i]]},
    "z-Drehung", {GraphicsComplex[wdrehungz[w], Polygon[i]]}]},
  Axes -> True, Boxed -> True, 
  Switch[x, "Verschiebung", PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}, {0, 5}}, 
   "Parallelprojektion", PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}, {0, 5}}, _, 
   PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]], {{a, 1, "x-Richtung"}, 
  Switch[x, "Verschiebung", 0, "Streckung", 0, "Parallelprojektion", 
   0, _, -3], 3},
 {{b, 1, "y-Richtung"}, 
  Switch[x, "Verschiebung", 0, "Streckung", 0, "Parallelprojektion", 
   0, _, -3], 3},
 {{c, 1, "z-Richtung"}, 
  Switch[x, "Verschiebung", 0, "Streckung", 0, "Parallelprojektion", 
   0, _, -3], 3},
 {{w, 0, "Winkel (in \[Degree])"}, 0, 360},
 Button["Reset", a = 1; b = 1; c = 1; w = 0],
 {x, {"Streckung", "Verschiebung", "Parallelprojektion", "x-Drehung", 
   "y-Drehung", "z-Drehung"}, ControlType -> PopupMenu},
 Initialization :> 
  (verschiebung := {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {a, b, 
      c, 1}};
   k := PolyhedronData["Cube", "VertexCoordinates"];
   Short[i = PolyhedronData["Cube", "FaceIndices"]];
   streckung[a_, b_, c_] := k.{{a, 0, 0}, {0, b, 0}, {0, 0, c}};
   wuerfel[a_, b_, c_, M_, l_] := 
    ReplacePart[
     Transpose[
       Insert[Transpose[l], 
        ConstantArray[1, 
         Map[Part[Dimensions[l], Sequence @@ #] &, {1}]], 
        Map[Part[Dimensions[l], Sequence @@ #] &, {2}] + 1]].M, {{_, 
        4}} :> Sequence[]];
   wdrehungx[a_] := 
    k.{{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[a Degree], -Sin[a Degree]}, {0, 
       Sin[ a Degree], Cos[a Degree]}};
   wdrehungz[a_] := 
    k.{{Cos[a Degree], -Sin[a Degree], 0}, {Sin[a Degree], 
       Cos[a Degree], 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
   wdrehungy[a_] := 
    k.{{Cos[a Degree], 0, -Sin[a Degree]}, {0, 1, 0}, {Sin[a Degree], 
       0, Cos[a Degree]}};
   )
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I have to show each transformmatrix. when you choose "streckung" for example, you should see the transformmatrix streckung with the manipulated variables a,b and c.

Comment: Please include your code showing what you've tried. What you've included above is not valid code.

Comment: Maybe what you want is: Row[{Matrixform[mat],Graphics3D[]}]

Comment: Someone should write a Mathematica function that guesses what a question is asking. May be wolfram alpha can handle this, since it is an AI program also.

Comment: @Nasser ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/z7N3d.png)

Comment: @Nasser We could add a new gray button to our JS collection http://i.stack.imgur.com/z7N3d.png

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way, basically as in my comment:

```
Manipulate[
 GraphicsRow[{streckung[a, b, c] // MatrixForm, 
   Graphics3D[{Switch[x, 
      "Streckung", {GraphicsComplex[streckung[a, b, c], Polygon[i]]}, 
      "Verschiebung", {GraphicsComplex[
        wuerfel[a, b, c, verschiebung, k], Polygon[i]]}, 
      "Parallelprojektion", {GraphicsComplex[
        wuerfel[a, b, c, verschiebung, k], Polygon[i]], Green, 
       Polygon[Transpose[
          ReplacePart[
           Transpose[
            wuerfel[a, b, c, verschiebung, 
              k].{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}], {{_, 2}, {_, 
              4}, {_, 6}, {_, 8}} :> Sequence[]]][[{1, 2, 4, 3}, 
          All]]], Blue, 
       Polygon[Transpose[
          ReplacePart[
           Transpose[
            wuerfel[a, b, c, verschiebung, 
              k].{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}], {{_, 3}, {_, 
              4}, {_, 7}, {_, 8}} :> Sequence[]]][[{1, 2, 4, 3}, 
          All]]], Red, 
       Polygon[Transpose[
          ReplacePart[
           Transpose[
            wuerfel[a, b, c, verschiebung, 
              k].{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}], {{_, 5}, {_, 
              6}, {_, 7}, {_, 8}} :> Sequence[]]][[{1, 2, 4, 3}, 
          All]]]}, 
      "x-Drehung", {GraphicsComplex[wdrehungx[w], Polygon[i]]}, 
      "y-Drehung", {GraphicsComplex[wdrehungy[w], Polygon[i]]}, 
      "z-Drehung", {GraphicsComplex[wdrehungz[w], Polygon[i]]}]}, 
    Axes -> True, Boxed -> True, 
    Switch[x, "Verschiebung", PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}, {0, 5}}, 
     "Parallelprojektion", PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}, {0, 5}}, _, 
     PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]]}], {{a, 1, 
   "x-Richtung"}, 
  Switch[x, "Verschiebung", 0, "Streckung", 0, "Parallelprojektion", 
   0, _, -3], 3}, {{b, 1, "y-Richtung"}, 
  Switch[x, "Verschiebung", 0, "Streckung", 0, "Parallelprojektion", 
   0, _, -3], 3}, {{c, 1, "z-Richtung"}, 
  Switch[x, "Verschiebung", 0, "Streckung", 0, "Parallelprojektion", 
   0, _, -3], 3}, {{w, 0, "Winkel (in \[Degree])"}, 0, 360}, 
 Button["Reset", a = 1; b = 1; c = 1; 
  w = 0], {x, {"Streckung", "Verschiebung", "Parallelprojektion", 
   "x-Drehung", "y-Drehung", "z-Drehung"}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}, 
 Initialization :> (verschiebung := {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 
      0, 1, 0}, {a, b, c, 1}};
   k := PolyhedronData["Cube", "VertexCoordinates"];
   Short[i = PolyhedronData["Cube", "FaceIndices"]];
   streckung[a_, b_, c_] := k.{{a, 0, 0}, {0, b, 0}, {0, 0, c}};
   wuerfel[a_, b_, c_, M_, l_] := 
    ReplacePart[
     Transpose[
       Insert[Transpose[l], 
        ConstantArray[1, 
         Map[Part[Dimensions[l], Sequence @@ #] &, {1}]], 
        Map[Part[Dimensions[l], Sequence @@ #] &, {2}] + 1]].M, {{_, 
        4}} :> Sequence[]];
   wdrehungx[a_] := 
    k.{{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[a Degree], -Sin[a Degree]}, {0, 
       Sin[a Degree], Cos[a Degree]}};
   wdrehungz[a_] := 
    k.{{Cos[a Degree], -Sin[a Degree], 0}, {Sin[a Degree], 
       Cos[a Degree], 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
   wdrehungy[a_] := 
    k.{{Cos[a Degree], 0, -Sin[a Degree]}, {0, 1, 0}, {Sin[a Degree], 
       0, Cos[a Degree]}};)]
```

[image]

Comment: Bill, there is also few problems with the original code. `k` has delay on it even though it is constant. `k` is being passed around as argument `L` in function `wuerfel`, which makes no sense, since `k` is constant an already in the initialization section. `verschiebung :=` is in the initialization section, yet it depends on control variables. Lots of calls to `Dimensions[k]`, yet `k` do not change. These could be all made constants so that no need to made the same calls all the time since the value do not change.

Comment: @Nasser -- It could be made to look (and act) a lot nicer, but I was responding to the OPs question about how to display the matrices along with the plot.

Comment: Sure, I understand, I was not criticizing you :) just pointing out some issues in original code.

Comment: Thanks for the moment, now you can see the matrix and the graphic.
Another problem is, that the graphic is now very small. How can I get this bigger?
I want it to look like here: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PolarAreaSweep/
On top the matrix, a delimeter and the graphic in that size like in my uploaded code.

Comment: Have you looked at the code at that demonstration? Downlaod it and you will see how they did it: the code starts with `Column[{Text@TraditionalForm@Style[Row[{ ... `  so they use a combination of `Column` and `Row` (instead of `GraphicsRow`) but the idea is the same. Another useful command is `ImageSize` though you have a lot of flexibility in the sizing of graphics commands.

Comment: Ok, I will try it...

Comment: That's the way I fixed the problem :-)

I only used:    `Column[{ Style[streck[a, b, c] // MatrixForm, FontSize -> 18, FontColor -> Black],
Graphics3D[{},]}, Dividers -> {False, 2 -> Gray}]`
It looks like the same as in the PolarAreaSweep.

Comment: Imitating the demonstrations is a great way to learn!